# How to go through each of the entry for a particular ID in the table and classify the IDs?

Tags: sql, select, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to go through all the IDs and classify each ID as `Car only`, `Bike only`, `both`, and ignore anything with truck. In the end I would like to see only one ID with specific Product_category.

Structure of the table is like this:

| ID | Product_names |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | car123 |
| 1 | car234 |
| 1 | bike123 |
| 1 | bike3 |
| 1 | bike8 |
| 1 | truck23 |
| 1 | truck9 |
| 2 | truck89 |
| 2 | truck98 |
| 2 | car34 |
| 3 | bike98 |
| 3 | bike12 |
| 4 | car2343 |
| 5 | car323 |
| 5 | bike87 |

Result:

| ID | Product_category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | both |
| 2 | car only |
| 3 | bike only |
| 4 | car only |
| 5 | both |

I tried to use coalesce and max in this way,

```
 select  id,  
 coalesce(max(case when name like 'car%' and name like
 'bike%' 
              then 'both' end),
          max(case when name like 'car%' then 'car_only' end),
          max(case when name like 'bike%' then 'bike_only' end)
          )
  from test
  group by 1;
```

But this is wrong because it would be searching for a name with both car and bike in its name, which is not possible and once it finds a car it ends there.

I am using this code in snowflake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first CTE formatting the names so that the product_names contains only the values car and bike as per the requirement.

In the second CTE doing a string aggregation

In the final query using a case statement on the aggregated string to find in which product category the ID fits in.

```
with cte as (
select 
    id, 
    case 
        when lower(product_names) like '%car%' then 'car' 
        when lower(product_names) like '%bike%' then 'bike' 
        when lower(product_names) like '%truck%' then null  
        else null 
    end as product_names
from tableName ) 

, cte2 as (
select 
    id,
    listagg(distinct product_names) within group (order by product_names) as product_names 
from cte 
    group by 1
)
select 
    id, 
    case 
        when product_names = 'bikecar' then 'both'
        when product_names = 'car' then 'car only'
        when product_names = 'bike' then 'bike only'
    end as product_category 
from cte2 
    order by 1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewirte it with GROUP_CONCAT

```
  select  id, 
   CASE WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(`Product_names`, '')  LIKE '%car%'
            AND GROUP_CONCAT(`Product_names`, '')   LIKE '%bike%' THEN 'Both'
   WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(`Product_names`, '') LIKE '%car%' THEN 'car'
   WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(`Product_names`, '')  LIKE '%bike%' THEN 'Bike'
   ELSE 'Neither' END 'type'
  from table1
  group by 1;
```

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Both |
| 2 | car |
| 3 | Bike |
| 4 | car |
| 5 | Both |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6DnntlqI)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is to extract only valid means of transportation (i.e. remove *trucks*), and then - using `min` and `max` aggregation functions (which is OK as you're checking only two vehicles) find the final result.

```
with temp as
  (select id, substring(product_names, 1, 3) pn
   from test
   where substring(product_names, 1, 5) <> 'truck'
  )
select id,
  case when min(pn) = 'bik' and max(pn) = 'car' then 'both'
       when min(pn) = 'bik' then 'bike only'
       when min(pn) = 'car' then 'car only'
  end as result
from temp
group by id;
```

which results in

```
        ID RESULT
---------- ---------
         1 both
         2 car only
         3 bike only
         4 car only
         5 both
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yHSNZTox) that illustrates it.